# How to use onclick with table row and googlemaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a standard implementation of google maps, and a list of results in a table next to it.

I want to open an info window each time a row in the table is clicked. What is the correct implementation? Here's my start:

JS

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Comment: we need more details, e.g.: how do you populate the table?

Answer (score 1):

When in the need to populate (or generate) the table as well as the elements (e.g, tbody, tr, th/td, etc) w/in it, I'd strongly suggest building them in the DOM way.

Suppose the returned result is a simple 1D-array, in the 3rd parameter ([success](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), which is the callback function) of your jQuery AJAX call:

```
$.get(
    url,
    data,
    function (data) {
        if (data) {
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            for (var i in data) {
                var tr = document.createElement("tr"),
                th = document.createElement("th"),
                td = document.createElement("td");
                th.innerHTML = i;
                td.innerHTML = data[i].key;
                tr.appendChild(th);
                tr.appendChild(td);
                table.appendChild(tr);
                document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).appendChild(table);
                /**
                 * here comes what you asked for
                 */
                $(tr).click(function () {
                    // do whatever you gotta do w/ it
                });
            }
        }
    },
    "json"
);
```

Note: Example shown using the shorthand method!

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't answer my question though. I have a TR element in HTML that I want to add an onClick event to and open a map marker. How would I do this?

Comment: First of all, you have to create a google.maps.InfoWindow() instance variable and make sure it is in the visible scope, then in the above example (the commented "do whatever you gotta do w/ it") add:
infowindow.open(map, marker);
That should do the trick. :)